How to Bulk Update Safety & Compliance Information Using SP API with POST_PRODUCT_DATA Feed
I need to bulk update the Safety & Compliance information for all products using the SP API and the POST_PRODUCT_DATA feed type. It's critical for me to include Safety & Compliance data for new products being added and also to perform partial updates for all existing products.
The issue is that the feed is not accepting the SafetyDataSheetURL element (where I need to provide a link to the document), and the same applies to other related tags, even though they are described in the XSD.
Before suggesting the use of the JSON_LISTINGS_FEED, I want to clarify the challenge: in our database, all products are currently categorized under the general type PRODUCT. The new feed type does not support this product type, and at the moment, we do not have the resources to validate and reclassify a large number of products under their correct types. This reclassification will be addressed later.
Right now, my priority is to ensure that by December 13, products are added with Safety & Compliance information included. We plan to transition to JSON_LISTINGS_FEED after this deadline.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
